# Is There Any Solution Of the 6174 Problem?

Tags: number-theory

I remember when I was a small child, I read about the Problem of 6174 that if we follow the algorithm of abstract any number and its reverse several times, then we must reach a invariant number 6174 at some step. I also read that this problem was unsolved. But time has flew by. So is there any solution to this problem now?

Comment: 6174 tells me Kaprekar's constant but I don't see unsolved connections?? Perhaps, I am wrong too.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this only pertains to four-digit numbers, so of course it's been solved (and WP even has a couple graphics illustrating the solutions). Am I not aware of something here?

Comment: Where did you read that this problem was unsolved ? There are not only a finite number of possibilities, but a relative small number of possibilities. With some effort, the problem could be easily solved without any electronic help. So, the solution should have been found very shortly after the problem has been "invented" , even if this was before the computer era.

Comment: @Peter . What about the general case, not only in base ten and not only just 4 digits. Starting with a non-rep-number, do we always reach a fixed point, or are there cycles of length >1? Is there a unique fixed point?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet This is another "story".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6174_%28number%29) is the relevant Wikipedia article, referenced in the comments.

The problem is "solved" in the sense that it is easy to check (using a computer) that all 4-digit numbers except repdigits do end up at 6174.

On the other hand, it doesn't seem that there is any more satisfying and principled *explanation* of why this process should end up at the same fixpoint, when this is not the case for 5-digit numbers.